# ng-click doesn't work when html is load from php

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

Why when i load this button from the php the ng-click doesn't work ?, I'am using angular and I'm loading all this from the angular controller, and when i put the button directly in the view of the html it works but when i try to load it nothing happens, please help

```
$open = 'ng-click="openbol('.$id.')"';

            $actions  = '<button '.$open.' data-id="'.$id.'" class="btn btn-xs blue btn-bol"> BoL</button>';

return $actions;
```

if I do this it works with the onClick, but it doesn't work with the ng-click

```
$open = 'onClick="window.open("reports/bol.php?bol="+id)"';

            $actions  = '<button '.$open.' data-id="'.$id.'" class="btn btn-xs blue btn-bol"> BoL</button>';
```

this is the functions I'm calling from the  angular controller

```
this.openbol2 = function(){
        alert("JA");
    }

    $scope.openbol = function(id) {
        self.openbol2(id);
        window.open("reports/bol.php?bol="+id);
    };
```

Comment: I've never come across anyone wanting to use `PHP` to generate the `Angular` markup. That seems like flawed logic, and defeats the purpose of using `Angular`. Correct me if I'm wrong though.

Comment: You should just create your markup templates, then use the controller (angular) to interact with your backend.

Comment: That button it's inside a datatable which I'm creating in the php class, so I need to know

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to say is that I don't think it's possible. It probably has to do with when Angular is being instantiated.

Comment: What I'd recommend is to make a call to your backend, and assign that to `$scope`.